# Open a new tab link in the same flutter webview

Tags: android, flutter, webview, hyperlink, mobile-development

I created a flutter android application based on **flutter_webview_plugin**, the problem is that it can't open **new tab links**.

Comment: you can check https://flutterawesome.com/allows-you-to-add-an-inline-webview-or-open-an-in-app-browser-window/

Comment: This isn't really a question, it's a comment. The assumption is that you are trying  to open 'new tab links'? Please explain what you are actually trying to do and perhaps explain what you have tried (with code ideally)

Comment: the initial post ended with , how do you do that please